# Tengo un PEDO salvador

Tags: traducción

Me gustaría saber qué significa la palabra **"pedo"**, utilizada por Bersuit Vergarabat en la canción "Espíritu de Esta Selva".

> Tengo un PEDO salvador, nacido en Latinoamerica,
>
> Don Leopardo corazón, espiritu en esta selva...

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to use this word as fart, drunkenness, etc. But also  it's a slang word for a *serious trouble* or in a sense of *"coolness"* expression.

Some examples of using the PEDO word are:

> Tengo un PEDO en mi trabajo.
>
> > *I have a serious problem at work.*
>
> Todo el PEDO me cayó a mi.
>
> > *All the troubles felt down on me.*
>
> Mi compañero de cuarto es muy buen PEDO.
>
> > *My roomie is so cool.*

...and there you go.

Comment: This meaning is completely unknown in Argentina, where BV are from.

Comment: https://dem.colmex.mx/ver/pedo Mexican site with Mexican terminology.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different meanings for [*pedo*](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=pedo), among them

- ventosidad (fart/toot)
- borrachera (drunkenness)
- fiesta (gathering for fun) This one seems to be used almost exclusively in El Salvador and Mexico, according to the RAE's entry.

Since [the lyrics of this song](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=33648) are a little bit weird and nonsense, there is no possible way of telling for sure which meaning the author intended.

Don't get me wrong. There are fabulous artist who have written poetry or lyrics in this same fashion. First that comes to my mind could be Federico García Lorca with writings such as *Poeta en Nueva York*. Context is useless to establish any sense in these words.

This said, if I have to say that *borrachera* or *fiesta* provide a much better poetic meaning than *ventosidad*.

Comment: _"Que los deseos salgan de estado de sitio del cuerpo y el alma"_. Yo voto por la ventosidad.

Comment: @Rodrigo No, la metáfora es clara acerca de la liberación de los deseos que se liberan de un "estado de sitio" donde están reprimidos. El pedo hace alusión a la borrachera o un sentimiento simil borrachera independiente del alcohol

Answer (score 0):

tengo un pedo salvador podría querer decir "este estado lisergico me salva de las penurias de haber nacido en latinoamericA"

Answer (score 0):

La canción habla del terrorismo de Estado que vivo Argentina y Latinoamérica en los años 1970 y 1980. En si, la letra hace un pedido de recuperación de los valores, sueños e ideales. En si, la canción anhela la liberación del ser humano y la transformación de la conciencia hacia el crecimiento y el desarrollo. Es una letra con mucho sentido lastima los burros que no entienden nada .

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio